# SELENIUM JAVA - Verify partial content of a string

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

I would like to verify the partial value of a string I get from a web page. I give an example the string is "Incident 1946721 Updated" and I would like to insert a check that verifies that the two words Incident are present as prefix and Updated as suffix. how can I do?

the html code where the text is present this is:

```
<div class="modal-body"><button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: -10px;">×</button><div class="bootbox-body">Incident 1946721 Updated</div></div>
```

Comment: You can check the `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` Java methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code :

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bootbox-body']")).getText();

if(value.startsWith("Incident") && value.endsWith("Updated")) {
    System.out.println("Test Pass");
}else {
    System.out.println("Test Fail");
}
```

Let me know if you have further query.